# Run C++ function from AS3

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, flash

Can't fugered out how to import C++ library into flash and run C++ function within it? 
Maybe there is some tools that make this stuff simple and painless? The way I see it:

```
// AS3
var n:Number = (C++).getSomeData();


// C++
int getSomeData(){
  int n;
  n = 2 + 2;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communication between c++ and actionscript 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683797/communication-between-c-and-actionscript-3)

Comment: Don't think so. I have c++ class, that should be somehow integrated in to the swf file. Output result should be looks like html+swf uploaded on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a special c++ compiler for that. The project is called CrossBridge:

http://adobe-flash.github.io/crossbridge/